# Running multiple kubectl commands in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

I'm trying to create a dashboard where I can see the status of my pods within my cluster. So I have a bash script that goes something like:

```sh
SERVICE_ONE=$(kubectl get pods | grep service-one | grep -E -- 'CrashLoopBackOff|Terminating|Error|Fail')
SERVICE_TWO=$(kubectl get pods | grep service-two | grep -E -- 'CrashLoopBackOff|Terminating|Error|Fail')
SERVICE_THREE=$(kubectl get pods | grep service-three | grep -E -- 'CrashLoopBackOff|Terminating|Error|Fail')

if [ ${#SERVICE_ONE} = 0 ]
then
  SERVICE_ONE_STATUS="GOOD"
else
  SERVICE_ONE_STATUS="BAD"
```

I then post these results to a GUI. The only problem is that I have almost 20 of these `kubectl` commands, which altogether, causes the program to take over 2 minutes to run. I tried doing something like:

```sh
KUBE_OUTPUT=$(kubectl get pods)
SERVICE_ONE=$(grep service-one <<< ${KUBE_OUTPUT} | grep -E -- 'CrashLoopBackOff|Terminating|Error|Fail')
SERVICE_TWO=$(grep service-two <<< ${KUBE_OUTPUT} | grep -E -- 'CrashLoopBackOff|Terminating|Error|Fail')
SERVICE_THREE=$(grep service-three <<< ${KUBE_OUTPUT} | grep -E -- 'CrashLoopBackOff|Terminating|Error|Fail')
```

But this doesn't work since the kube output isn't saved in the same format as when I run it plainly on my terminal (there's spacing issues, no newlines, etc.). I was wondering if there was a better way of executing multiple `kubectl` commands at once?

Comment: Don't run multiple commands: run just one with all details for all pods in `json` format and use other tools like `jq` to parse that long clob.

Comment: Ok I figured spewing all the information into `jsonpath` might be the way to go, but it seemed like it wouldn't keep the same format. I'll probably have to change my logic for a lot of my commands, but it's probably the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since, running kubectl command every time to get the pod details will take the time.

i tried kubectl get pods with -o=jsonpath something like below

```
$  VAR=$(kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{'\t'}{.status.phase}{'\n'}{end}"$'\r' | grep -E -- 'CrashLoopBackOff|T
erminating|Error|Fail|Running')
```

This will filter the result with NAME and STATUS of the pod.
the output would be like

```
$ IFS=' '
$ echo $VAR
my-deployment-55bc8b77dd-8plsw  Running
my-deployment-55bc8b77dd-crlbx  Running
my-deployment-55bc8b77dd-jqqx4  Running
my-deployment-55bc8b77dd-mnm5k  Running
my-deployment-55bc8b77dd-zndvs  Running
```

Now you can again filter based in the pod name

```
$ SERVICE=$(echo $VAR | grep my-deployment-55bc8b77dd-8plsw)
```

the output will  be

```
$ echo $SERVICE
my-deployment-55bc8b77dd-8plsw  Running
```

now split the result and display the status as you like.
If this is not what you are looking for. plz put a comment.

Comment: I was really just missing this step: `VAR=$(kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{'\t'}{.status.phase}{'\n'}{end}"$'\r' | grep -E -- 'CrashLoopBackOff|T
erminating|Error|Fail|Running')`, I ended up using `echo ${VAR} | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '/service-one/{getline; print}' | grep -E -- 'CrashLoopBackOff|Terminating|Error|Fail'` to check the status of each pod matching my service

Comment: glad it helped!!:)